# How to create left, right, and center frames with pack?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a left and right frame right now and tried creating a center frame but the problem is the left frame takes up more space and pushes the center frame to the right so any widgets I put in it aren't actually centered. Is there any way to make it work?

```
    self.leftside = ttk.Frame(self)
    self.leftside.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, anchor=W)

    self.center = ttk.Frame(self)
    self.center.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER)

    self.rightside = ttk.Frame(self)
    self.rightside.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=RIGHT, anchor=E)
```

Comment: I can't exactly reproduce the issue, please provide a [mre], as I have tested they normally expand correctly taking up the max space, if a widget is placed in either of the frames, the rest may shrink to allow space for the widget if the geometry is limited

Comment: Are you asking how to guaranteed that the center frame is centered, regardless of the contents of the left and right frame?

Comment: Don't forget to pass the appropriate flags when you put widgets into one of the frames.  Also, in general, if you want three equi-sized frames, the grid manager might be a better fit (pun intended) than the pack manager, since you can adjust the "weighting" of the frames in the layout. Also remember: when you create three frames like above, each frame is completely separate from the other two and the layout of each one can be managed any way you want.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Sorry for the late response. Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Gary02127 Thanks, I'll try grid whenever I get back to my computer but what do you mean by appropriate flags?

Comment: each layout manager has its own set of unique options. For example, pack() has fill, expand, etc. And grid() has row, column, rowspan, columnspan, sticky, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to guarantee that the center section says centered, `grid` is going to be a better choice than `pack` since you can configure `grid` to force the other two columns to be the same size, and to have the center region grow or shrink to fill the rest of the space.

It would look something like this:

```
    self.leftside.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.rightside.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
    self.center.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure((0,2), uniform="equal")
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```